# Chart in Power apps gives wrong data from choice field of sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

Chart in Power apps gives wrong data from choice field of sharepoint list

here is my item:

AddColumns(
GroupBy(
AddColumns('Micro Focus Escalation Tracker',"Stat",Status.Value),
"Stat",
"GroupData"
),
"CountByStatus",
CountRows(GroupData)
)

Here is actual data from sharepoint list

[image]

This is what Powerapps shows (Wrong Numbers)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test this works fine.

[image]

Please refresh the app to compare the result.

[image]

If the issue persists, create a new choice field with fewer values and check the results.